# How do i transfer a final string from one activity to another in android?

Tags: android, final, data-transfer

I know about this and it works fine

```
    Intent i1 = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
    i1.putExtra("username","the name");
    startActivity(i1);
```

and this in the next layout:

```
    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
```

but i need to tranfer a final string, I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
    public static final String ADMIN_USERNAME= "user";

    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,SignUp.class);
    intent.putExtra("admin_username",ADMIN_USERNAME);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and this in the next layout:

```
    public final String ADMIN_USERNAME= getIntent().getStringExtra("admin_username");
```

im getting this error:

```
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Can you  give more information? For example what error you are taking? Maybe full class for letting us to check your namespace scope?

Comment: For string constants like you have there, just make it static and access it directly in the other activity.

Comment: it works as per i know

Comment: @EmreAktürk updated the error im getting

Comment: @DanielNugent can you demonstrate please?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a string constant as static like this:

```
public static final String ADMIN_USERNAME= "user";
```

you don't need to use intent extras to access to the value in another activity, just access the ADMIN_USERNAME string constant directly:

```
if (someString.equals(MyActivity.ADMIN_USERNAME)) {
    //Do something....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is null. İt's a early call in lifecycle

> String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("admin_username");

Make sure you call this line in onCreate if you are calling inside onAttach

Also make sure your key is correct. Please notice I fixed it also as "admin_username"

Good luck

Emre